# Windows phone 8.1: Need suggestion on what database should I use

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, azure-sql-database

For my Windows phone project (it's a Universal app), I have a set up that has a country and a phone number in one of the page. There are about 7 other pages that requests the user for additional information. But for starters, let's just stick with the first one, that asks for the country and the phone number.

I read through a million posts in Stackoverflow and other websites alike, to know what database system is best to implement with the sort of app I am going to be developing, or hoping to develop.

Here're my findings:

1. Azure SQL: I have an Azure account and I can use the Azure SQL service to store the user-input data directly to the database (when the app goes live), or while in the testing phase. But I got to know that feature isn't really working well as windows phone cannot readily update the data to Azure SQL, on realtime basis. Is it so?
2. MySQL: I thought I'd create a local MySQL database, for testing purposes, so as I input the data (in the emulator perhaps), the database saves it. I am unsure how I can implement this. I can't find any article I can read that can help me with this. There are with ASP.net, but it isn't what I am going to be using.
3. SQLite: I know for a fact the data can be stored locally, by using SQLite, but I could like to know if the locally stored data can be later updated on a server-side machine (i'd prefer Azure SQL, but MySQL is also OK with me). If it can be, i wouldn't mind settling with it. If it can't, what can I do?

It all boils down to this: *What's the easiest way to store data entered in a textbox* (lol, yeah!) *to a database (locally or server-side)?*

Your efforts to help me will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can stay on Azure SQL if you have an account. 
It works fine and it updates database on the go (sends json as far as I remember), so you shouldn't worry about data being stored in a cloud. Moreover, it is super-easy to use it for your needs (store data from textbox).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If you're sure this would fix the problem, I wouldn't mind sticking to it. I am just looking for more suggestions from other people :)

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL will get your bootstrap the fastest for your application. There is no need to deploy MySQL or SQLite and managing your DB. There should not be any concern about updating the DB live from the app.